# VIP future champion gas moped won't stay running

Tags: engine, motors, moped

Okay so my moped sits over night I go to start it and it turns over and starts for about 3 seconds and shuts off. Well it will not start again until I put raw fuel or starter fluid in breather. After that it'll run at a high rev. It'll calm down and the only way it stays running is if I steady give it gas if I don't give it gas it'll shut off. But I noticed after it warms up it can sit anywhere between 15-30min and still start up without starter fluid or gas but it still won't stay running if I don't give it gas. HELP!!!!

Comment: Take a look at your spark plug(s).  Do they have deposits on them?

Comment: No I got new wires and spark plug

Comment: Sounds like a fuel issue. I would start with cleaning the carb. This is the first step for most issues like these.

Comment: I agree.  You may need a carb adjustment as well.  Also, I assume you are aware of where the choke is and how it works on your bike?

Comment: I can't find a choke NO WHERE!!  Carb is brand new